# Simplifying ArcTan[Cos[u], Sin[u]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I am trying to evaluate the following expression in *Mathematica*:

$$ 
\bigg| \frac{\left(1-z^{-2}\right)^n}{\left(1-z^{-1}\right) \left(2-z^{-n}-z^{-1}\right)} \bigg|^2
$$

Here $z$ is the complex exponential (of the $Z$ transform) and is given by:
$
z=e^{-2i\pi f/f_s}
$,
where $f_s$ is a constant.

In order to evaluate this, I wrote the following code in *Mathematica*:

```
z := Exp[(2*Pi*I*f/fs)];
h := Abs[(1 - z^-2)^n/((1 - z^-1) (2 - (z^-1) - z^(-n)))];
Simplify[h^2, Element[f, Reals]] // ComplexExpand // TrigReduce
```

*Mathematica* evaluates the expression, however doesn't completely simplify it. I get terms of the following kind in the denominator:

> `ArcTan[Cos[(2*f*Pi)/fs], Sin[(2*f*Pi)/fs]]`

The `ArcTan` function can obviously be simplified to just `2*f*Pi)/fs`.

Is there any way to get *Mathematica* to do this on its own?

I have posted an image of the code and result I get in the figure.

[image: result]

Comment: `N` is a reserved word. Use lowercase for your symbol names

Comment: Thanks fro your quick reply. I tried replacing N by small case, however I am still getting the same results.

Comment: Try `{ArcTan[Cos[(2*f*Pi)/fs], Sin[(2*f*Pi)/fs]], (2*f*Pi)/fs} /. {f -> 2, 
  fs -> 1}`.  You'll see they aren't equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use $n$ and $h$ (not $N$ and $H$) in your code.  (Please change your problem accordingly).  Second, be sure to use semicolons at the end of each line.  Third, make the `ArcTan` simplification explicitly:

```
z := Exp[(2 π I f/fs)];
h := Abs[(1 - z^(-2))^n/((1 - z^(-1)) (2 - (z^(-1)) - z^(-n)))];
Simplify[ComplexExpand[h^2], Element[f, Reals]] //. 
 ArcTan[Cos[aa__], Sin[aa__]] -> aa
```

$\frac{2^{2 n-3} \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi  f}{\text{fs}}\right) \sin
   ^2\left(\frac{2 \pi  f}{\text{fs}}\right)^n}{-2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  f
   n}{\text{fs}}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  f}{\text{fs}}-\frac{2 \pi  f
   n}{\text{fs}}\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  f}{\text{fs}}\right)+3}$

Here, the additional transformation is:

```
ArcTan[Cos[aa_], Sin[aa_]] -> aa
```

which means everywhere there is a term of this form (where I arbitrarily chose the variable name `aa` to refer to any set of variables), replace the `ArcTan[...]` with `aa`.

Comment: Thanks David for your comment, the last line of your code uses a "->" symbol, I assume this forces Mathematica to convert every expression on the left to the one on the right? (Sorry about the basic question, but I have never used Mathematica before.). One more thing. Why do the Cos and Sin have the arguments "aa__"?

Comment: @SaqibShah. Look up `Rule` and `ReplaceRepeated` in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to keep in mind that ArcTan[Tan[x]] is not always equal to x. When x is between -Pi/2 and Pi/2, it is valid. So we have

> In[24]:= ArcTan[Tan[x]]
>
> Out[24]= ArcTan[Tan[x]]

And

> In[25]:= FullSimplify[ArcTan[Tan[x]], -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2]
>
> Out[25]= x

Similarly, it follows that

> In[26]:= FullSimplify[ArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]], -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2]
>
> Out[26]= x

Therefore, in the present question's context we have:

> In[27]:= FullSimplify[  ArcTan[Cos[(2*f*Pi)/fs], Sin[(2*f*Pi)/fs]],
>   -fs < 4 f < fs]
>
> Out[27]= (2 f [Pi])/fs